# Ionic page constructor only called once

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Right now I have a list of buttons on one page populated from my database.  I am trying to have the app on button click segue to a new page with one element on the page being pre-populated with the button value.  The issue is the constructor on the second page only gets called once with the initial value of the id being passed, so when you go back and select a different id the second view is still populated with the first ID selected.

below is the first controllers function for segueing:

```
getSingleTest(id){
        console.log("view-test argument from button");
        console.log(id);
        this.navCtrl.push(SingleTestPage, {"testID": id});
    }
```

below is the code for the second controller:

```
export class SingleTestPage {

    testIDField: any;

    testID: any;
    singleTestData: any;

    constructor(public events: Events, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public singleTest: SingleTestProvider, public testService: TestService) {
        console.log("COnstructed single test");

        this.testID = this.navParams.get('testID');

        this.populatePage(this.testID);
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        console.log('ionViewWillEnter SingleTestPage');
        //this.testID = this.navParams.get('testID');

    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
    }

    populatePage(id){
        this.singleTest.getTest(id)
        .then(data => {
            console.log("single-test.ts data");
            console.log(data);
            this.singleTestData = data;
            console.log(this.singleTestData.testID);
            this.testIDField = this.singleTestData.testID;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });


    }
}
```

I have tried to implement a custom back button which removes the page from the push stack, but that didn't work either.

Comment: use `ionViewDidLoad` not the `constructor` for initializing code with ionic

Answer (score 0):

The constructor won't get called again if the page was cached. The ionViewWillEnter lifecycle hook should get called again when you view the page again. I see that you have some code in there setting the id that's commented out, I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

For that use

ionViewDidEnter(){}

Method to solve your Problem.

Comment: if I put the variable assignment in the ionViewDidEnter(){} then how would I be able to pass in the parameter.  Can't I only do that through the constructor?